# Can I insert the contents of a text file as email body?

Tags: sql-server, email

I have set up a SQL Agent Job that emails some recipients - the email has a text file as an attachment.

```
-- Start T-SQL 
USE msdb 
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='DBMailProfile', 
 @recipients='xxx.xxx@xxx.co.uk', 
 @subject='Blah blah blah', 
 @body='An attachment has been included in this email.', 
 @file_attachments='\\auz-svx-akk93\log.txt' 
-- End T-SQL
```

Everything works fine.

Instead of sending the file as an attachment, is it possible to read the *contents* of the text file and send it in the email body?

Comment: Certainly using a text files content as body of an email message is possible. What is your question here exactly?

Comment: Ok, thank you for confirming that it is possible.  My question would therefore be, how do I place the *contents* of a text file into an email as the body?

Comment: Which obviously depends on _how_ you create and send that email message which you did not tell us...

Comment: Sorry, it's via SQL Agent and uses this bit of code: -- Start T-SQL
USE msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='DBMailProfile',
  @recipients='xxx.xxx@xxx.co.uk',
  @subject='Blah blah blah',
  @body='An attachment has been included in this email.',
  @file_attachments='\\auz-svx-akk93\log.txt'
-- End T-SQL

Comment: @TimRichards I've taken the liberty of editing your question to include the code in your comment. HOpefully this helps you get a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've resolved it.

I created a table, used the BULK INSERT command to populate it with the contents of the text file and then modified the bit of T_SQL to reference that table instead of attaching the text file.